# Sequential API call using Rxjs in Angular with null return

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a scenario where I need to make a sequential API call using `RxJs` in `Angular`, which I have done but I am facing this null error. For calling the 2nd api I will receive and `id` from the first API which can be `null` or `undefined`. So what I wanted to If if id is not available I will return `of(null)` otherwise will return the response. But there are some typescript error. Following is what I have done so far.

```
of(personId).pipe(
  take(1),
  switchMap((personId: string) => {
    return this.personService.getById(personId).pipe(
      concatMap((person: Person) => {
        const classId = person?.class?.id || null;
        let class$ = of(null);

        if (classId) {
          class$ = this.classService.getById(classId); // Will return Observable<Class>
        }

        return combineLatest([of(person), class$])
      })
    )
  }),
  tap(([person, class]) => {
    console.log('Person: ', person);
    console.log('Clas: ', class);
  })
).subscribe()
```

`class$ = this.classService.getById(classId);`

On this line I am facing the 'TS2322: Observable is not assignable to Observable`

Any suggestion on how do I resolve this? Also can this code be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just replace the conditional logic with this line

```
   let class$= classId?this.classService.getById(classId):of(null)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very silly of me.. I should have seen this, not sure what I was thinking. Probably tried to overthink this simple stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The observable that is returned by `this.classService.getById` is different to the one that is returned by `of(null)`, hence you cannot reassign the `class$` variable with it.

However your problem can easily be overcome by simply using a ternary operator to define `class$` as follows:

```
const class$ = person?.class?.id ? this.classService.getById(classId) : of(null);
```

Comment: Thank you. It was very silly of me to not see this also since @Fan Cheung answered first so I accepted that answer but I will upvote your answer as well

Answer (score 0):

First of all this `of(personId)` it seems weird.

Why not:

```js
this.personService.getById(personId).pipe(
  concatMap((person: Person) => {
    const class$ = person?.class?.id
      ? this.classService.getById(person?.class?.id)
      : of(null);
    return combineLatest([of(person), class$]);
  })
).subscribe(/*...*/);
```

The error `TS2322: Observable is not assignable to Observable` I think that it is self-described.